# Query to find all objects with more than one primary location

Tags: sql

I have a table object. A object should have only one primary location. I want to find all those objects who have more than one primary location. Table structure:

```
objectid  isprimary location
123       1         abc
456       0         sdg
789       1         jhv
789       1         dfkj
```

The query should display

```
789      1    jhv
789      1    dfkj
```

Basically I want all objects whose isprimary is 1 for more than 1 location.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objectid IN (
    -- subquery to find ids of all objects having more than one primary location
    SELECT objectid
    FROM objects
    WHERE isprimary = 1 -- take only rows that show primary locations
    GROUP BY objectid -- "squeeze" all these rows with the same objectid to a single row
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- COUNTs number of original rows in each "squeezed" row
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First limit records for isprimary  = 1 and than group by objectid. Return only those that have count > 1:

```
select * FROM the_table WHERE objectid IN (SELECT tab2.objectid FROM the_table tab2 WHERE isprimary =1 GROUP BY  objectid HAVING COUNT(1) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the object ids which have multiple Primary locations, then the following query will do it.

```
WITH data_set AS
     (SELECT 123 objectid, 1 isprimary, 'abc' loc
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 456 objectid, 0 isprimary, 'sdg' loc
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 789 objectid, 1 isprimary, 'jhv' loc
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 789 objectid, 1 isprimary, 'dfkj' loc
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT   objectid
    FROM data_set
   WHERE isprimary = 1
GROUP BY objectid
  HAVING COUNT (loc) > 1;
```

But if you want all details of the record, then partition by will be helpful.

```
WITH DATA_SET AS
     (SELECT 123 OBJECTID, 1 ISPRIMARY, 'abc' LOC
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 456 OBJECTID, 0 ISPRIMARY, 'sdg' LOC
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 789 OBJECTID, 1 ISPRIMARY, 'jhv' LOC
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 789 OBJECTID, 1 ISPRIMARY, 'dfkj' LOC
        FROM DUAL),
     PROC_DATA AS
     (SELECT OBJECTID, ISPRIMARY, LOC,
             COUNT (LOC) OVER (PARTITION BY OBJECTID) AS CNT
        FROM DATA_SET
       WHERE ISPRIMARY = 1)
SELECT OBJECTID, ISPRIMARY, LOC
  FROM PROC_DATA
 WHERE CNT > 1;
```